# pipenv install error ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_file_on_disk'

Tags: python, windows, pipenv

I'm trying to create a python virtual environment with `pipenv 2018.11.26` on `Windows [Version 10.0.14393]` and `Python 3.5.2 (Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit))`. These are all mandatory settings that I can't alter.

I get the following cryptic error:

```
C:\project_path\pipenv install

Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\project_path\Pipfile
Using C:/Anaconda3/pythonw.exe (3.5.2) to create virtualenv…
[  ==] Creating virtual environment...ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_file_on_disk'

Failed creating virtual environment
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-        packages\pipenv\cli\command.py", line 254, in install
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:           editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\pipenv\core.py", line 1741, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\pipenv\core.py", line 574, in ensure_project
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\pipenv\core.py", line 506, in ensure_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       python=python, site_packages=site_packages,     pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:   File "c:\anaconda3\lib\site-    packages\pipenv\core.py", line 935, in do_create_virtualenv
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:       extra=[crayons.blue("{0}".format(c.err)),]
[pipenv.exceptions.VirtualenvCreationException]:
Failed to create virtual environment.
```

The main cause sees to be an import error, but I can't find anything called `ensure_file_on_disk`.

I have tried to uninstall and re-install `pipenv` to no avail.

Also, since I'm running behind a proxy, I have created the system environment variables `no_proxy`, `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` but it hasn't worked either.

By the way if I try to run `pipenv shell` it gives me the exact same error, so it does not seem to be a connection problem after all.

Have you guys ever come across this issue?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1876

Seems to be a common issue.
@gaborbernat Has a solution and explanation in the link.

Comment: @gaborbernat says to uninstall both global and user specific installations of the package and install just one. Since I have not found a way to uninstall pipenv for a specific user such as 'pip uninstall --user pipenv' I have uninstalled it using simply 'pip uninstall pipenv' and reinstalled it. This has not solve the problem. Is there a way to see if there are any global installations of pipenv? Thanks

Comment: @AhaduTsegayeAbebe you might need to run the uninstall command multiple times, see Vinay's answer below

Answer (score 6):

I resolved this issue. In my case, it is because of multiple versions of virtualenv are installed. I removed all the versions using `pip3 uninstall virtualenv` multiple times. Thereafter I've installed the latest virtualenv again.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by uninstalling the `virtualenv` package and reinstalling a compatible version which I found to be `20.0.25`

Answer (score 0):

In my case updating pip helped

`python3.6 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

next uninstall virtualenv

`python3.6 -m pip uninstall virtualenv`

and install it

`python3.6 -m pip install virtualenv`

Comment: you have a typo in your first line's upgrade flag

Answer (score 0):

This is a version issue. On Windows, I typed the following commands:

```
> py -m ensurepip --upgrade
> py -m pip install --upgrade pip
> py -m pip install --upgrade pipenv
```

And it works!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It looks like this question was already satisfactorily anwered, at least with a clear consensus. In this case, please elaborate on how your answer adds to existing content.

Answer (score -1):

```py
pip3 install --user --upgrade cython virtualenv==20.0.28
```

Comment: Try adding an explanation to your answer rather than just writing code, that will help users understand what your answer offers compared to other options and how it differs.